# Does cloud compatible complex event proceesing (CEP) framework exist?

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I have used ESPER's Complex Event Processing (CEP) framework for my work. It is working in standalone system very well. I do not know whether any cloud compatible CEP framework exists or not. By cloud compatible, i mean, it should scale on multiple machines. Please tell me if you are aware of any such CEP framework.

Thank you very much